# Find $P(A \cup B \cup C)$ given they are pairwise independent but not mutually independent

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

Find an upper bound for $P(A \cup B \cup C)$ given they are pairwise independent but not mutually independent. A, B and C are fixed and I know to use the inclusion-exclusion rule to get their union, but I don't know how to get the intersection since they are pairwise independent but not mutually independent

Comment: What are A, B, and C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not 100% clear, but I will try to answer it assuming that the probabilities of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are fixed, and we are trying to see how high $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ can go.

Let's suppose that $a=P(A)\ge b=P(B)\ge c=P(C)$. From inclusion-exclusion principle:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}P(A\cup B\cup C)&=&P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)\\&\le&P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(B\cap C)\\&=&a+b+c-ab-ac\end{array}$$

On the other hand, this limit can be achieved: see the following Venn diagram:

[image]

(note that $a-ab-ac+bc\ge a^2-ab-ac+bc=(a-b)(a-c)\ge 0$).

Comment: @Joe indeed. 

Added a clarification that what I am solving here is the problem of finding the upper bound with $a=P(A), b=P(B), c=P(C)$ fixed. I don't see any other way to interpret the question, but then, it wouldn't have hurt if that had been explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Yes this is the appropriate way to interpret the question

Comment: +1 this is a very neat and general answer!  So basically, because of pairwise independence, the $ab, bc, ca$ terms are known, and the only "unknown" is $P(A\cap B \cap C) = x$.  Obviously $x \le ab, bc, ca$.  By the ranking convention this reduces to $x \le bc$, and by the example $x=bc$ is possible, and therefore gives the tight upperbound.  In fact, this also shows the _only_ way to achieve the upperbound is when $x=bc$, i.e. when $B\cap C \implies A$.

Comment: @antkam To be very precise, this means that the upper bound is achieved when $B\cap C\implies A$ with 100% probability (i.e. $P((B\cap C)\setminus A)=0$).

Comment: hahaha, of course, of course...  always forgot about those darned zero-prob events!

Comment: I still am a little confused. How is $x \le bc$?

Comment: @DylanY Because $A\cap B\cap C\subseteq B\cap C$.

Answer (score 0):

I originally posted this as an edit but was asked to repost as an answer, so here we go!
The bound derived by @ Stinking Bishop is indeed tight, provided the condition $b+c \leq 1$ is satisfied. To see this, note that $a+b+c-ab-ac=1-(1-a)(1-b-c)$, which is a valid probability bound  ($\leq 1$) if and only if $b+c \leq 1$ or the smallest two probabilities add up to at most one (assuming $a<1$ otherwise the union probability is trivially one).
So it would be more precise to say that the tight bound on the union of three pairwise independent (but not mutually independent) Bernoulli events, given their fixed marginal probabilities is $$\min\left(a+b+c-a(b+c),1\right), \quad \mbox{where}\quad 1 > a \geq b \geq c \geq 0$$

Interestingly, this result can be generalized beyond three events to an arbitrary number of events. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence#Probability_of_the_union_of_pairwise_independent_events) on pairwise independence shows that the tight bound on the union of $n$ pairwise independent Bernoulli events $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ with given probabilities $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$ (assumed to be arranged in order of increasing probabilities) is given as:

$$\max P({\cup}_i A_{i})  =  \min\left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_{i}-p_{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_{i}\right),1\right)$$
which is at most one when the sum of the smallest $n-1$ probabilities is at most one.

The proof is non-trivial and can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.00516.pdf).